# Open GL Lighting Difficulties

Tags: c#, vb.net, opengl, tao-framework

**Background**

Currently I am esentially making a CAD viewer which will be used in a larger system. I have been reading a ton of information about learning Open GL and I am quite far along. I can import the file, display it, and navigate using keyboard controls.  I am trying hard to understand and set up proper lighting now.

**Problem**

After some discussion bellow, I realize that I don't have a shader loaded which is why I am having my problems.  In doing some research I have found some shader files, fragment.glsl and vertex.glsl which are written in C. Will this be a problem since I am writing my code in C#/ VB.net? I don't think so.

Now I am having a problem with compiling the shading, and linking the shaders to my code.  I found a handy source for compiling:

http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~brosz/wiki/pmwiki.php/CSharp/08022008

In this article, a function is created to compile a shader.  The compiler requires a stream to which is then passed on to the compiler. I have this function I created to read the shader to a stream:

```
Public Function path_to_stream(ByVal path As String) As System.IO.Stream
    Dim bData As Byte()
    Dim br As System.IO.BinaryReader = New System.IO.BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
    bData = br.ReadBytes(br.BaseStream.Length)
    Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(bData, 0, bData.Length)
    ms.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length)
    Return ms
End Function
```

Towards the end of my draw function I try to load using the shader function:

```
vertexShader = path_to_stream(Application.StartupPath & "\default.frag")
    fragmentShader = path_to_stream(Application.StartupPath & "\default.vert")

    vs_object = Helpers.OpenGLUtilities.createAndCompileShader(vertexShader, Gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fs_object = Helpers.OpenGLUtilities.createAndCompileShader(fragmentShader, Gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    program = Helpers.OpenGLUtilities.createAttachLinkShaderProgram(vs_object, fs_object)
```

I get an error message however that the shader could not be compiled. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Here is what my model looks like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UvN4Tj8.png]

Looks decent but not great..

[image: http://i.imgur.com/G2TJt12.png]

Looks terrible..

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SXZ7C5S.png]

Just as bad..

**Update**

Since it was asked below, this is my method for doing the actual drawing of my triangles.  The listview it is getting the information from is basically the STL file, which contains the normal vector and then three points which make a triangle.

```
        Gl.glRotatef(rotX, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
        ' Rotate on x
        Gl.glRotatef(rotY, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F)
        ' Rotate on y
        Gl.glRotatef(rotZ, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F)
        ' Rotate on z
        Gl.glTranslatef(X, Y, Z)

        'Gl.glPolygonMode(Gl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, Gl.GL_FILL)
        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES)
        Gl.glColor3f(part_color.R, part_color.G, part_color.B)


        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Do Until i + 4 >= ListView1.Items.Count
            Gl.glNormal3f(ListView1.Items.Item(i).SubItems(0).Text, ListView1.Items.Item(i).SubItems(1).Text, ListView1.Items.Item(i).SubItems(2).Text)

            Gl.glVertex3f(ListView1.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            Gl.glVertex3f(ListView1.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            Gl.glVertex3f(ListView1.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            i = i + 4
        Loop
        Gl.glEnd()
```

My main drawing sub:

```
Private Sub display()


    Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    ' Clear the Color Buffer 
    Gl.glPushMatrix()
    ' It is important to push
    ' the Matrix before calling
    ' glRotatef and glTranslatef
    Gl.glRotatef(rotX, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    ' Rotate on x
    Gl.glRotatef(rotY, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F)
    ' Rotate on y
    Gl.glRotatef(rotZ, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F)
    ' Rotate on z
    Gl.glTranslatef(X, Y, Z)
    ' Translates the screen
    ' left or right, up or down
    ' or zoom in zoom out
    ' Draw the positive side of the lines x,y,z
    Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES)
    'Gl.glColor3f(0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glColor4f(0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F)

    ' Green for x axis
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glVertex3f(10.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glColor3f(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    ' Red for y axis
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glColor3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F)
    ' Blue for z axis
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 10.0F)
    Gl.glEnd()

    ' Dotted lines for the negative sides of x,y,z
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LINE_STIPPLE)
    ' Enable line stipple to
    ' use a dotted pattern for
    ' the lines
    Gl.glLineStipple(1, &H101)
    ' Dotted stipple pattern for
    ' the lines
    Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES)
    Gl.glColor3f(0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F)
    ' Green for x axis
    Gl.glVertex3f(-10.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glColor3f(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    ' Red for y axis
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, -10.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glColor3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F)
    ' Blue for z axis
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glVertex3f(0.0F, 0.0F, -10.0F)
    Gl.glEnd()

    Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_LINE_STIPPLE)
    ' Disable the line stipple
    Gl.glPopMatrix()
    ' Don't forget to pop the Matrix

    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING)

    Light1Position = {0.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F}

    ' Enable Default Light
    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_AMBIENT, Light1Ambient)
    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_DIFFUSE, Light1Diffuse)
    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_POSITION, Light1Position)
    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_SPECULAR, Light1Specular)

    ' Enable Lighting
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT1)




    draw_extras()


    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
    Gl.glColorMaterial(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)
    Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_SPECULAR, MaterialSpecular)
    Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_SHININESS, SurfaceShininess)

    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)

    Glut.glutSwapBuffers()
End Sub
```

My draw_extra sub:

```
Public Sub draw_extras()
    Dim texture As UInteger() = New UInteger(0) {}


    If allowdraw = True Then

        find_center_of_part()


        Gl.glPushMatrix()


        Gl.glRotatef(rotX, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
        ' Rotate on x
        Gl.glRotatef(rotY, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F)
        ' Rotate on y
        Gl.glRotatef(rotZ, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F)
        ' Rotate on z
        Gl.glTranslatef(X, Y, Z)

        Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES)
        Gl.glColor3f(part_color.R, part_color.G, part_color.B)


        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Do Until i + 4 >= ListView1.Items.Count
            Gl.glNormal3f(ListView1.Items.Item(i).SubItems(0).Text, ListView1.Items.Item(i).SubItems(1).Text, ListView1.Items.Item(i).SubItems(2).Text)

            Gl.glVertex3f(ListView1.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 1).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            Gl.glVertex3f(ListView1.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 2).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            Gl.glVertex3f(ListView1.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(0).Text - avgx, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(1).Text - avgy, ListView1.Items.Item(i + 3).SubItems(2).Text - avgz)
            i = i + 4
        Loop
        Gl.glEnd()




        ' Disable the line stipple
        Gl.glPopMatrix()

    End If

End Sub
```

Here is what the STL file looks like:

[image]

It starts with the normal vector, then is followed by three points for the triangle, then another normal vector, and so forth. That is all my loop is doing.

**Next Update**

I tried changing the code for the light to be:

```
 Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING)

    Light1Position = {X, Y, Z, 0.0F}

    ' Enable Default Light
    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_AMBIENT, Light1Ambient)
    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_DIFFUSE, Light1Diffuse)
    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_POSITION, Light1Position)
    Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_SPECULAR, Light1Specular)


    ' Enable Lighting
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT1)
```

The X, Y, Z variables should match the camera since earlier in the code it translates the camera:

```
Gl.glTranslatef(X, Y, Z)
```

No light to be found:

[image]

Any guidance at all would be greatly appreaiciated.  I tagged this as both C# and VB .NET since either answers would work for me.

Comment: Why not do you a simple shader instead of trying to use old and deprecated OpenGL stuff ?

Comment: I guess I don't know how to make a proper shader in VB .NET.

Comment: Shaders  isn't related to your programing language choice.

Comment: Well yea I understand that but I still have to write one then which I don't know how to do.

Comment: Try here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13640380/770931

Comment: Ok Zardoz89, I have fragment.glsl and vertex.glsl based on this article: http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/05/introduction-to-modern-opengl-3x-with.html  Will it be a problem if those files are written in C and I am writing the rest of my code in C# / VB .NET? Do I need to convert?  From there, how do I load my shader files? Most examples are in C which is where I am having my difficulty from. Things don't translate nicely always.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Your shader is written in glsl (OpenGL Shading Language). That's why the file-ending is .glsl. It doesn't matter in which language your program is written. Just use the string of your shader code (dependent on how you load your shader) and compile it with the OpenGL Functions.

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking then is how to compile the shader using Open GL functions? What I tried for compiling is listed above but I get an error message stating that the shader couldn't be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

You could also write your own shader to render your actual object, which will calculate diffuse lighting, maybe even specular if you want. From there, you could also do texture mapping, shadows, normals, etc.

There is an excellent tutorial by OpenGL on the shader code [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/lighting.php), and you can find a tutorial on using GLSL with C# on the internet.

Comment: This is helpful but I have a hard time converting things in that example to C# / VB .net since that example is in C. Know of any similar examples that are in one of those languages?

Comment: Well, that tutorial isn't it C, it's in GLSL. You seem to already have a shader compiler working, so you could just write a shader using this code and try rendering the object with it.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the answers here, if your goal is to have simple lighting and you are just starting to learn OGL, you should not have to write your own shaders. OpenGL has built in functionality to handle this for you, as I'm sure you've seen in many tutorials. Although this functionality is no longer supported, which prompts many people to condemn it despite its obvious benefits,  it will make your learning process much easier.

Since it's been mentioned that you have enabled lighting, I'd like to know how you currently draw your model. If you use immediate mode (calling glVertex for every vertex), do you also call glNormal to supply normals? Without normals OpenGL has no information about how to calculate the lighting for your model. If you do not use immediate mode, please explain exactly what you do. Submitting your code would be a big help, as I have no idea what you are currently doing, and OpenGL has a million ways for you to make a mistake.

As an addition: The shader code in the tutorial you linked appears to be overly complicated for a beginner, you should not use that.

I'd like to put this in a comment instead of an answer, but my reputation is currently insufficient.

Please ask any questions in the comments of my answer, so a step-by-step resolution of your problem can be achieved.

Comment: Henk De Boer, I know that my question is closed because of the auto accept time period but my question definitely is NOT answered. I have updated my question to show you the code I am using.  I know that I can no longer give you points, but if you could still help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do agree with you that all I need is simple lighting. My goal is not to render an entire scene but just to show a part that I can rotate.

Comment: Are you sure the model data is correct? If the normals in the model are wrong, it won't be right in OpenGL either. Also, although the extra code is a good start, it would be best to upload your entire code, or at least the part concerning lighting.

Comment: I would think that the model data is correct since other programs read the same file without problem. I updated my question again to include my entire draw code.

Comment: I also included a sample of my STL file import (it is very large to show more but you get the idea)

Comment: Why are the coordinates of the triangles in the STL so huge? It looks like the entire model is translated 3000 units away. Your code seems to be doing all it needs to do for lighting, but I can't be sure. Your light is currently very far away from your model, unless you translate your model closer to the origin, I can't tell because I don't know the XYZ values. My last thought is trying to move your model closer to the light, see if it makes any difference. I've upvoted your question so hopefully someone else will look at it, problem is that there's already a few answers here.

Comment: Is there any way to make my light stay with my camera so that no matter where I go in space, I always have my light with me?

Comment: Yes, simply link the position of the light to your camera. So, just like you update your camera every frame, call Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_POSITION, cameraPosition) every frame.

Comment: I updated my question.. I added a line that does like you said but no dice on good lighting.. Any other suggestions? By the way your help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Also shouldn't rotation be taken into account for light to be  where the camera is?

Comment: Hank, I think I figured most of it out so I want to say thank you very much for your help. I have one last problem but just remade the question since this one has gotten messy. Feel free to take a look:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095379/open-gl-positioning-lighting-at-camera-always

Answer (score -1):

I can see nowhere when you turned on lightning. It's okay that you turned on 2 lights with `glEnable(GL_LIGHTn)` but the whole stuff is not enabled. There's an [article](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_lighting.html) if you're confused. I'm saying that because your models look like aren't shaded at all, they all have the same colour and that colour not depends on how the surface directs to the light source, doesn't depend on the normal if you set it I should say. I think two light is far enough for that purpose, for demo projects I usually have my lightning with one diffuse light, I don't even set the ambient or the specular part. Like this way:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f } );
```

It's pretty simple but you have all you probably want, basic shading, and not just one big colour splotch in your screen forming your shape's border.

Comment: The enum value is `GL_LIGHTING`, not `GL_LIGHTNING`. Which is already enabled in the OP's code.

Comment: I have  Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING) already in my code above.  If shading isn't enabled how do I enable it? I have Gl.glShadeModel(Gl.GL_SMOOTH) in my init code. Do I need more?

Comment: You are right and I've corrected it. And do you set normal vectors too?

Comment: Yes I do. Since this is a cad viewer, I have many triangles. Each triangle has 3 points and a normal vector set

Comment: If you send me the code and the media I will take a look at.

Comment: Please see the above comments. I have updated my question but my problems are not having a shader. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Actually, you don't have to have a shader to earn agreeable results, the code should be working you wrote. I presume the lights may be placed too far, but I'm not sure if it is a mistake, diffuse colours should still be there. On the other hand I can send you a working .NET shader loader class.

Comment: If you could that would be incredibly helpful to see a properly written VB .NET lighting and shading example. I have had a hard time finding examples in C#, let alone VB .NET.

Comment: I would definitely vote for yours if you could provide that .NET shader loader class